# VF phone number display format

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, css

I would like to do one input text of phone number with bottom border only and the phone is separated into two parts: area code + number on the next format :

XXX-XXXXXXX

Within one input.

It's mean that the hyphen ("-") will be added automatically after 3 letters.

Can anyone help me with it please?

Thanks!

Comment: What you have tried so far? Can you post your code?

Comment: I just have two inputs with a span that holds my hyphen ("-").. 
I wanted to know if this need to be a known format function in JS or maybe css..

Comment: More answers available on stackoverflow